# is there a code formatting tool or keyboard short cut to automatically remove the trailing spaces within a quote especially in CSS styling?

Tags: html, css, eslint, prettier

I want to be able to automatically remove the space after and before the quotes in the inline styling. Especially for large codebase. is there a tool like Prettier or ESLint or VScode extension that can do this?

spacing

Answer (score 0):

You can enable whitespace trimming at file save time from this plugin in VScode: [plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=lonefy.vscode-JS-CSS-HTML-formatter)